# How to select all data corresponding to the 3 latest dates for each ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID   | DATE       | OTHER | OTHER 
----------------------------------
ID45 | 8/22/2020  |       |
ID45 | 9/12/2020  |       |
ID45 | 12/13/2020 |       |
ID45 | 7/14/2020  |       |
ID56 | 3/15/2020  |       |
ID56 | 2/19/2020  |       |
ID56 | 9/24/2020  |       |
ID56 | 5/18/2020  |       |
ID72 | 7/20/2020  |       |
```

I would like to see all the data (all columns) related to the last 3 dates of an ID
The result would be in this case:

```
ID   | DATE       | OTHER | OTHER 
----------------------------------
ID45 | 12/13/2020 |       |
ID45 | 9/12/2020  |       |
ID45 | 8/22/2020  |       |
ID56 | 9/24/2020  |       |
ID56 | 3/15/2020  |       |
ID56 | 2/19/2020  |       |
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    [ID],[Date]
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rn
FROM YourTable) AS A
WHERE A.rn<=3
```

Answer (score 0):

If in case you don't want to use windowed function, simpler solution is:

```
SELECT *
    FROM TABLE
        WHERE DATE IN (SELECT TOP 3 DATE FROM TABLE ORDER BY DATE DESC)
    ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Comment: Top is sqlserver mysql equivalent is limit